# Quarkus Reactive throws "Session is currently connecting to database"

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

I'm running into a problem with Quarkus Reactive when running load tests. It seems connections aren't freed up fast enough.

The endpoint basically does a database lookup by a received code, and then stores a new event with the entity as a relation.

```
    @GET
    @PermitAll
    @Path("s/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Uni<Response> request(@PathParam("code") String code) {
        return myService.fetchEntityByCode(code)
                .onItem().invoke(entity-> {
                    //persist the events here
                    persist(SomeEvent.builder().entity(entity).build());
                })
                .onItem().transform(entity-> {

                  Response.ResponseBuilder builder = new ResponseBuilderImpl();

                  //do some other things to build the response
 
                  return builder.build();
                });

    private void persist(MyEvent myEvent) {
        Panache.withTransaction(myEvent::persist)
                .onFailure().invoke(throwable -> log.error("Persisting failed", throwable))
                .subscribe().with(p -> {
                   //just a dummy subscriber to get "fire&forget" behaviour
                });
    }
```

When I run the load test with k6, I'm getting the error below. I'm assuming this is related because connections are not freed up again, and then after a while there are problems creating new connections to the database.

```
2022-01-30 17:04:04,865 DEBUG [org.hib.res.jdb.int.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-6) `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` was enabled.  This setting should only be enabled when you are certain that the Connections given to Hibernate by the ConnectionProvider have auto-commit disabled.  Enabling this setting when the Connections do not have auto-commit disabled will lead to Hibernate executing SQL operations outside of any JDBC/SQL transaction.
2022-01-30 17:04:05,052 ERROR [com.lau.lin.MyResource] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-11) Persisting failed
2022-01-30 17:04:05,052 ERROR [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-11) Mutiny had to drop the following exception: io.smallrye.mutiny.CompositeException: Multiple exceptions caught:
    [Exception 0] io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Timeout
    [Exception 1] java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000060: Session is closed
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnFailure.lambda$call$3(UniOnFailure.java:108)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureTransform$UniOnFailureTransformProcessor.onFailure(UniOnFailureTransform.java:54)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onFailure(UniOperatorProcessor.java:48)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:887)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2325)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:144)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:51)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage.subscribe(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:35)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureTransform.subscribe(UniOnFailureTransform.java:31)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureFlatMap$UniOnFailureFlatMapProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnFailureFlatMap.java:101)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureFlatMap$UniOnFailureFlatMapProcessor.dispatch(UniOnFailureFlatMap.java:83)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureFlatMap$UniOnFailureFlatMapProcessor.onFailure(UniOnFailureFlatMap.java:60)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onFailure(UniOperatorProcessor.java:48)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onFailure(UniOperatorProcessor.java:48)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onFailure(UniOperatorProcessor.java:48)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2162)
    at io.vertx.core.Future.lambda$toCompletionStage$2(Future.java:362)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onFailure(FutureImpl.java:153)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitFailure(FutureBase.java:75)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryFail(FutureImpl.java:230)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Mapping.onFailure(Mapping.java:45)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitFailure(FutureBase.java:75)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryFail(FutureImpl.java:230)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryFail(PromiseImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.onFailure(PromiseImpl.java:54)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:43)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.pool.SqlConnectionPool$1PoolRequest.lambda$null$0(SqlConnectionPool.java:202)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool$Cancel.run(SimpleConnectionPool.java:666)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.CombinerExecutor.submit(CombinerExecutor.java:50)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool.execute(SimpleConnectionPool.java:240)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool.cancel(SimpleConnectionPool.java:629)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.pool.SqlConnectionPool$1PoolRequest.lambda$onEnqueue$1(SqlConnectionPool.java:199)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:893)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:860)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:50)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.emit(DuplicatedContext.java:168)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.emit(AbstractContext.java:53)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.run(VertxImpl.java:883)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000060: Session is closed
        at org.hibernate.reactive.pool.impl.ProxyConnection.withConnection(ProxyConnection.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.pool.impl.ProxyConnection.rollbackTransaction(ProxyConnection.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionImpl$Transaction.rollback(MutinySessionImpl.java:459)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionImpl$Transaction.lambda$execute$3(MutinySessionImpl.java:441)
        at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualSupplier.get(SlowContextualSupplier.java:21)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnFailure.lambda$call$5(UniOnFailure.java:133)
        at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnFailure.lambda$call$4(UniOnFailure.java:102)
        at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureFlatMap$UniOnFailureFlatMapProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnFailureFlatMap.java:92)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Timeout
```

and

```
2022-01-30 16:29:53,581 ERROR [com.lau.lin.MyService] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-10) Persisting failed: io.smallrye.mutiny.CompositeException: Multiple exceptions caught:
    [Exception 0] java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000061: Session is currently connecting to database
    [Exception 1] java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000061: Session is currently connecting to database
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnFailure.lambda$call$3(UniOnFailure.java:108)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureTransform$UniOnFailureTransformProcessor.onFailure(UniOnFailureTransform.java:54)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onFailure(UniOperatorProcessor.java:48)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:887)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2325)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:144)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:51)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage.subscribe(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:35)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureTransform.subscribe(UniOnFailureTransform.java:31)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureFlatMap$UniOnFailureFlatMapProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnFailureFlatMap.java:101)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureFlatMap$UniOnFailureFlatMapProcessor.dispatch(UniOnFailureFlatMap.java:83)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureFlatMap$UniOnFailureFlatMapProcessor.onFailure(UniOnFailureFlatMap.java:60)
16:30:23: Execution finished 'quarkusDev'.
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Comment: Have you resolved your issue ?

Comment: @godo57 never did any load tests anymore so I was not aware that this issue still exists